# Scala Play JSON: Turn a hashmap into json object instead of array

Tags: scala, play-json

For the given HashMap structure:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[scala.Option[java.util.UUID], scala.collection.immutable.List[crm.v1.auto.generated.customapis.CustomapisPublic]]
```

Json.toJson produces this:

```
[
    [
        "bb2b5475-8f27-4dd4-9221-05904177a666",
        [
            {
                "id": "5e700dab-e352-47d5-8ad8-0d9e16db8fbc",
                "time": 1616500566442,
                "isGroup": true,
                "name": "rapidx",
                "parentId": "bb2b5475-8f27-4dd4-9221-05904177a666",
                "projectId": "d531e915-afb0-42e9-9c90-831f0413794e",
                "teamId": "a03339d4-4ccc-48ea-8bd9-b506ad83c492"
            },
            {
                "id": "5287f6bd-2f55-4232-9064-a989ae5926f3",
                "time": 1616503457651,
                "isGroup": true,
                "name": "User",
                "parentId": "bb2b5475-8f27-4dd4-9221-05904177a666",
                "projectId": "d531e915-afb0-42e9-9c90-831f0413794e",
                "teamId": "a03339d4-4ccc-48ea-8bd9-b506ad83c492"
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        "5287f6bd-2f55-4232-9064-a989ae5926f3",
        [
            {
                "id": "db0f59ea-fbf0-4024-ad54-04ea387223b0",
                "time": 1616569959967,
                "description": "Post Daily data",
                "isGroup": true,
                "name": "Post Daily data",
                "parentId": "5287f6bd-2f55-4232-9064-a989ae5926f3",
                "projectId": "d531e915-afb0-42e9-9c90-831f0413794e",
                "teamId": "a03339d4-4ccc-48ea-8bd9-b506ad83c492"
            },
            {
                "id": "325c3d1f-d2bb-46b2-a708-db26484607c2",
                "time": 1616570029306,
                "code": "Future{\n    Results.Ok(“Patch user data working successfully”)\n}",
                "description": "patch user data",
                "isGroup": false,
                "name": "patch user data",
                "parentId": "5287f6bd-2f55-4232-9064-a989ae5926f3",
                "projectId": "d531e915-afb0-42e9-9c90-831f0413794e",
                "supportedMethods": [
                    "get",
                    "post",
                    "patch",
                    "delete"
                ],
                "teamId": "a03339d4-4ccc-48ea-8bd9-b506ad83c492"
            },
            {
                "id": "61c392b5-b482-4b2b-be2c-e94f40dfef2c",
                "time": 1616570221882,
                "code": "Future{Results.Ok(“Add config working successfully”)}",
                "description": "addConfig",
                "isGroup": false,
                "name": "addConfig",
                "parentId": "5287f6bd-2f55-4232-9064-a989ae5926f3",
                "projectId": "d531e915-afb0-42e9-9c90-831f0413794e",
                "teamId": "a03339d4-4ccc-48ea-8bd9-b506ad83c492"
            }
        ]
    ]]
```

While I want something like his:

```
{
 "uuid-1": [{...object-1...}, ...],
 "uuid-2": [{...object 1...}, ...],
 "uuid-n": [{...object 1...}, ...],
 null: [{...object 1}, .... ]
}
```

Any headsup will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want a `null` key? Does JSON allow that?

Comment: Yeah I checked and seems Json doesn't allow, and hence as suggested by you further modification was needed for underlying map. Now key of map are not of type Option[UUID], rather it's of type String.

Answer (score 0):

PlayJson knows how to work with a `Map[String, SomethingThatHasAWrites]`, so you can convert your keys to become Strings first.

Not sure what to do with the `null` though, that seems like a bad idea, maybe change to a dummy value?

```
 Json.toJson(data.map { 
    case (Some(key), value) => key.toString -> value 
    case (None, value)      => "missing"    -> value
 })
```

Comment: Yeah I turned null value  to `root`

Answer (score 0):

Co-incidentally I kind of tried something similar what @Thilo just suggested.

I added a map after my group, and turned the key type Option[UUID] to String.

```
mapField.map(a  => (a._1.map(_.toString).getOrElse("root"), a._2))
```

I also realised that PlayJson is really smart here, when there was null value, it opted for list/array based strucure. Now when there were no chances of ecountering a null value in place of key, it opted for Tree/Object strucure.

Perhaps, I guess PlayJson opts for list structure when there are non String based types in place of HashMap key, and opts for Treee structure if type of HashMap key is Number or String.

New structure looks like this:

```
{
    "root": [
        {....},
        {....},
        {....}
    ],
    "db0f59ea-fbf0-4024-ad54-04ea387223b0": [
        {...}
    ],
```